# how to make vertical line separator which can be covered by hover effect using css?

Tags: css, line, separator

I have a problem when making a vertical line separator for navigation menu.

When I makes a navigation, it's require a vertical line separator. But, when I hover the navigation menu, the vertical line separator cannot be covered by the hover effect, please see below image.

[image]

How to make the line separator covered by hover effect?

This is my CSS:

```
   .admin-functions{
        background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f0f0ff);
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px #0A78DC solid;
        display: table;
    }
    .admin-functions a{
        text-decoration: none;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .admin-functions a:hover{
        background : linear-gradient(#0abedc, #0a78dc);
        color: white;
    }
    .separator{
        border: 1px solid #0a78dc;
        margin-left:-2px;
    }
```

And this is my HTML:

```
    <nav class="admin-functions">
        <a href="#">Job Manage</a>
        <span class="separator"></span>
        <a href="#">Applicant Manage</a>
        <span class="separator"></span>
        <a href="#">Company Info</a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add :before for second and third a.

```
.admin-functions a:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -2px;
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(#0abedc, #0a78dc);
}
```

I think this should help you.

Remember to remove of the first a.